# GAE w/ Objectify - Can you query a HashMap?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

In GAE, when using Objectify, can you query a HashMap? If so how would would you write it?

```
ofy().load().type(MyClass.class).filter("hashMapfieldName", "keyQueryinggFor").list();
```

Does not seem to work where the `hashMapfieldName` is a `HashMap<String, String>`. I am looking to find entities where `hashMapfieldName` contains a certain key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like embedded classes, Objectify converts `Map<String, String>` to the low-level `EmbeddedEntity` object, which is not indexible. However, if you @Index your `Map` field (or embedded class field), Objectify will create a synthetic index that lets you query anyways.

Following your example, let's say you have a Map field named `hashMapfieldName` containing the mapping of strings `"key"` to `"value"`. This query syntax will return entities that have the pair:

```
ofy().load().type(MyClass.class).filter("hashMapfieldName.key", "value");
```

If you are just looking for key existence, try `filter("hashMapfieldName.key !=", null)`.

Comment: I am a little confused. In this example are you creating your own class with the members `String key` and `String value`, or are you still using a `java.util.HashMap`?

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now. But, what if I don't know they key name? I am looking for entities that contain that key in their `HashMap fieldName`. Probably should not have called it "value", lol sorry. I made the question more clear.

Comment: Sounds like you are testing for key existence. Which is to say, there is a value and the value is not null (assuming you do not consider null to be a valid value). The last sentence of my answer should set you straight.

Comment: I just got a bit confused when with `hashMapfieldName.key`. I thought you literally meant "key" like that had special meaning to the query, but what I now see you meant was something like `hashMapfieldName.keyQueryinggFor`. Thanks a million!

Comment: @stickfigure I have tried it and it works for me. However, how do you handle composite queries without having to know the fields beforehand inside your Map "hashMapfieldName". I have posted a question regarding this at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45322198/google-datastore-with-objectify-composite-queries-on-hashmap

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar case where I have stored device specific values in an embedded hashmap where the device id is the key, and I need to query for all entities that contain a certain value.

The suggested solution by stickfigure above does work in my test environment. But I realized I cannot use it the real application since it will not scale to the number of users we are projecting. This is because **Objectify will generate a property index for each hashmap key that I save**. In my case, that means that every user's device will have its own index, which could be 100000 indexes!

So instead, I went for this alternative approach:

- in the `@OnSave` method on the entity I store the values that I want to search for in a separate indexed list, that I only use for querying
- then I will do my filtered query like this:

  `ofy().load().type(MyEntity.class).filter("values", value)`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what `Objectify` does for `HashMap`.

But as per the docs, `HashMap` is not a supported field type in `Datastore`. Even if we `serialize` it and store, it will be stored as Blob which is by default `unindexded`.

So to my knowledge, `HashMap` cannot be queried as there is no indexes created for it.

Comment: If any else is 100% certain, please let me know. Otherwise looks like @Bharath is right.